# How to prevent other users other than 3 admin to access a webpage in php?

Tags: php

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
<?php
    //To search three admin username and validate it.
    $q = "SELECT * FROM login_admin";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$q);
    // Loop for retrieveing username form database.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $u_user = $row["username"];
    echo $u_user;
    // to check if the session's username is same as username in database.
    if(($_SESSION['username']) != $u_user)
    {
    header('Location:logout.php');
    } 
    }
    ?>
```

I just want to prevent other users to access a webpages directly typing it in address bar. Other users have there own username and password. But admin page also recognizing session variable of users.

Comment: Hey! Ronnie, Great, It is working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would define admin settings while login in.

Like:

```
$_SESSION['admin'] = true/false;
```

During a visit on one of your pages you can read this session and act on it:

```
if( ! $_SESSION['admin']) // '!' means if $_SESSION['admin'] == false.
{ 
// redirect to some other page? 
};
```

**Documentation:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php // Session
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php // If else

Answer (score 0):

define user types in user database such as: 1: admin, 2, moderator, 3: user
and define page permissions in database or in a config file or directly in that php file but at the top of condition that checks if user type has access permission in this php file.

example;

```
/*
* user database table example
* user types: 1: Admin, 2: Moderator, 3: User
*/
$user = ["id" => 1, "name" => "Musa ATALAY", "email" => "email@example.com", "type" => 1];

# example.php
<?php
    $pagePermissions = [1,2]; # only admins and moderators

    if(!in_array($user["type"], $pagePermissions)){
        exit("You dont have permissions to access this page!");
        # or
        header("Location: /403.html")
        # or whatever you want to do in this condition
    }

    # page codes
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a column of user_level to your users table.
2. Prevent access of that page from users other than user_level is admin

   // Write query to search active user level
   // Then check whether the user level is admin or basic

   if($row['user_level'] != 'admin'){
          echo "You are not an authorized user to access this page";
       }